# Trying to install UWP DesktopAppConverter gets "Access is Denied"

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

The Windows Store is unable to install the Desktop Converter on build 14393 here. It starts and gets an error 0x80073CF9. It seems to be only that, as I can download other apps fine.

So I am trying to install it from the zip file.

I have copied the files from DesktopAppConvert.zip into C:\Windows\System32.

I also copied BaseImage-14393 there.

First time I type desktopappconverter it prompted me for the name of the app, and so on.

Then when I go

```html
CMD PS C:\> .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Setup -BaseImage .\BaseImage-14393.wim -Verbose
```

I get : Access is denied.

What am I doing wrong ?

TIA

Comment: Hi Mitch, any updates on this issue? Looks like you have resolved it?

Comment: Hi Franklin. I finally reinstalled 14393 from scratch and immediately went to the Windows Store ; it installed Desktop App Converter for me quite nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, good, so if you think my answer is helpful and acceptable, please let me know;)

Answer (score 0):

> I get : Access is denied.

Please extract the DesktopAppConverter.zip to a **local folder**, like Desktop folder of current user

Also need to ensure the current user has the **Administrator** permission.

Run the following command from an **admin PowerShell window** to setup the converter

See [Set up the Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter)